# Textfield in Foreach with EnvironmentObject

Tags: foreach, textfield, swiftui

I'm trying to make two list of Textfield with a @EnvironmentObject but have "Use of unresolved identifier" problem

```
class ViewChange: ObservableObject  {
         @Published var Equipes: [Equipe] = EquipData
        }

        struct EquipView: View {
            @EnvironmentObject var ViewChange: ViewChange


            var body: some View {



                ForEach(ViewChange.Equipes) { item in
                   Text("Équipe \(item.name)") //work

                        ForEach(item.joueurs){i in
                           Text(i.name) //work
                           TextField("", text: $i.name) // "Use of unresolved identifier '$i'"        

                        }
              }


      }

   struct Equipe : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var numero: Int
    var name: String
    var joueurs: Array<Joueur>

}


    struct Joueur : Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
    }




    let EquipData = [
        Equipe(numero: 1, name: "Les Saiyans", joueurs: [Joueur(name: "Maximilien"),Joueur(name: "Paul")]),
        Equipe(numero: 2, name: "Rocket", joueurs: [Joueur(name: "Roger"),Joueur(name: "Sacha")])

    ]
```

Someone can explain to me clearly how I can proceed to have my dynamic textField list with the values ​​of ViewChange.Equipes ?

Comment: What is supposed to go into the text field?

Comment: the name of Joueur, for the Text(i.name) it work, it display every name of Joueur of Joueurs Array.     (Joueur = Player, Equipe = Team ). with my code I have  these Text items: "Equipe Les Saiyans, Maximilien, Paul, Equipe Rocket, Roger, Sacha". but I want text editable for the players name ( Joueur.name value)